# Cufoncanvas replace styles

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, cufon

How can I chnage the cufoncanvas css in IE8

```
<cufoncanvas style="left: 0px; top: 1px; height: 27px;" cufid="215">
```

I tried `$(document)`:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("cufoncanvas").css({
      top: '10px'
    });
});
cufon.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage to fix it by removing `$(document).ready(function()`

So that

```
$("cufoncanvas").css({

      top: '10px'
    });
```